# resize textarea dynamically with tailwind css and alpine js 3.x

Tags: javascript, html, tailwind-css, alpine.js

Not sure what is broken here, but this works perfectly in Alpine 2.x

This is to make the text area resize sorta how discord has it. As you type the text area gets bigger.

The action of typing or holding down shift + enter still resizes the box. But the first view is broken. You need to click on the input area and type a letter before it starts to work.

```
<textarea 
        x-data="{ resize: () => { $el.style.height = '5px'; $el.style.height = $el.scrollHeight + 'px' } }"
        x-init="resize()"
        @input="resize()"
        wire:model.defer="add_comment"
        x-on:keydown.enter="if (!$event.shiftKey) $wire.addComment()"
        placeholder="Send Message..." 
        class="text-base bg-blueGray-100 border-none w-full max-h-58  rounded-md  focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 resize-none"
></textarea>
```

On Alpine 2.x the text area correctly scales to show placeholder
[image]

On Alpine 3x. the text area doesn't scale for the placeholder.
[image]

Any ideas on what the issue might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed `x-init` and it resolved the issue.

Honestly not sure why it doesn't work, but the issue has been resolved.